# how to avoid undefined error while accessing service?

Tags: angularjs

I have created services in seperate file. But i am getting error in console saying `Cannot read property then of undefined`

This is the code which is failing

```
github.getUser($scope.username).then(onUserComplete, onError);
```

Here is my link to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQXRqO0hY3JGEIEcauVE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to actually return the promise returned by `$http.get()` service from your service methods, instead of just invoking it:

```
var getUser = function(username){
      return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
        .then(function(response){
          debugger;
          return response.data;
        });
    };
```